# Load value of one div into another

Tags: html, jquery

In the below code, I have three buttons - P1, P2 & P3 each of which has a card div below it.
On the right I have another div with text as "TEXT SHOULD BE DISPLAYED HERE".
I want that when I click on the button its respective data should replace the above text. For example, if I click on P2, the text in the right box should change to "Data for P2"

```
<body>
    <div class="row container">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <button data-val="p1">P1</button>
            
            <button data-val="p2">P2</button>
            
            <button data-val="p3">P3</button>
            
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="second">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <span>
                           TEXT SHOULD BE DISPLAYED HERE
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row container">
        <div class="card" data-val="p1">
            <div class="card-body">
                <span>
                    Data for P1
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card"  data-val="p2">
            <div class="card-body">
                <span>
                    Data for P2
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="card"  data-val="p3">
            <div class="card-body">
                <span>
                    Data for P3
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

How can I achieve this using jQuery? Please note that I don't just want to replace the text but the entire div in real scenario.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen for the click event on each button. At click you can get the text value associated to the button and copy it to the card:

```js
$('.row .col-lg-6 button').on('click', function(e) {
    var dVal = this.dataset.val;
    var cardEle = $(this).closest('.row.container').next().find('.card').filter(function(idx, ele) {
        return ele.dataset.val == dVal;
    });
    var txt = cardEle.text().trim();
    $(this).closest('.row').find('.col-lg-6 .second .card-body span').text(txt);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row container">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <button data-val="p1">P1</button>

        <button data-val="p2">P2</button>

        <button data-val="p3">P3</button>

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="second">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                        <span>
                           TEXT SHOULD BE DISPLAYED HERE
                        </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row container">
    <div class="card" data-val="p1">
        <div class="card-body">
                <span>
                    Data for P1
                </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card"  data-val="p2">
        <div class="card-body">
                <span>
                    Data for P2
                </span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card"  data-val="p3">
        <div class="card-body">
                <span>
                    Data for P3
                </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, is there a way to directly copy the entire div ? What if these divs below the button are in a different markup altogether and linked through some common attribute. How can I do that,then?

Comment: While this solves the case, I tried using a simpler method and it worked as expected as follows (on click of the button) $('.second .card').html($(this).next().html()); - by replacing the entire div instead. Now, the issue is, if I want to apply a different CSS to both the card divs,how can I do that while preserving the css for the second card div?

Comment: Add a dummy class....  Please, avoid to use **.html()**

Comment: Why not? How to copy the entire div then?

Comment: you need to use [jQuery.clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) plus append or insertafter....

Comment: Can you please tell me how? :/ I am unable to get the desired output. I just want the content inside the card to be cloned so that each card can have it's own unique css style. And in this example, I have only span class, but in real time scenario, there is a lot of content which I just want to clone at once with altering individual styles.

Answer (score 1):

use following jquery

```
 $(document).on('click', 'button', function (e) {
     spanText = $(this).next().find('span:first').text()
         
      $('.replace-text').text(spanText)
  });
```

add class `replace-text` to `<span>` of whom you want to replace text like

```
 <span class="replace-text">
    TEXT SHOULD BE DISPLAYED HERE
  </span>
```

**Demo**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.siblings * { 
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  color: lightgrey;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 15px;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).on('click', 'button', function (e) {
            spanText = $(this).next().find('span:first').text()
         
            $('.replace-text').text(spanText)
        });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <button data-val="p1">P1</button>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <span>
                        Data for P1
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button data-val="p2">P2</button>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <span>
                        Data for P2
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button data-val="p3">P3</button>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <span>
                        Data for P3
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="second">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <span class="replace-text">
                           TEXT SHOULD BE DISPLAYED HERE
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```